# ffmpeg: Convert any Video to padded and scaled 720p

Tags: ffmpeg

I looked for 2 hours through the documentation, but I couldn't figure it out.

I currently write a script and now I need to concat up to 10 videos with different ratios/framerates/codecs/size etc.

Currently I work with the following:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i part1.mp4 -i part2.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]pad=width=1280:height=720:color=black[v1]; \
 [1:v]scale=1280:720[v2]; \
 [v1][0:a][v2][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 0 output.mkv
```

This does attach the video but doesn't upscale the 1st video (which is in 640x480, the 2nd video is in 720p). I can put it somewhere with x and y, but it won't grow to the full screen.

And as I'm already asking, here's another question:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i part1.mp4 -i part3.mp4 -i part2.mp4 -filter_complex \
"movie=part1.mp4, scale=1280:720 [v1] ; \
 amovie=part1.mp4 [a1] ; \
 movie=part3.mp4, pad=width=1280:height=720:x=160:y=0:color=black, scale=1280:720 [v2] ; \
 amovie=part2.mp4 [a2] ; \
 movie=part2.mp4, scale=1280:720 [v3] ; \
 amovie=part2.mp4 [a3] ; \
 [v1] [v3] [v2] concat=n=3 [outv] ; \
 [a1] [a3] [a2] concat=n=3:v=0:a=1 [outa]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -qp 16 output.mp4
```

why does I have to write `concat=n=3:v=0:a=1 [outa]` but only `concat=n=3 [outv]`. When I also write `concat=n=3 [outa]` it will result in an error.

Comment: I was in the freenode ffmpeg chnael and they couldn' answer it and they said I should ask here...

Comment: Could you please add the console output for first question? Are you trying to join 2 videos of different sizes with the resultant video at 720p size? Also, ask second question separately.